# Flutter, how to force the scroll event to affect outer container?

Tags: flutter, scroll

I made a container which consists of several columns.
The first few columns are a text data.
The second part is also a container that has a several images inside.

This page is usually longer than the phone screen. So it will need scroll to reach the bottom.

But the problem is the second container that contains several images.
When I scroll, if I touch the the second column, it scrolls inside the column even though it doesn't need to. I want this scroll event to be applied to the outer(parent) container.

Anyone with idea?

I searched how to delegate the scroll event to the parent container in flutter but failed to find

Maybe somewhat like in Javascript
`$(window.parent.document).scroll(function() {});`

This is [My flutter code](https://github.com/challeyJJ/challey202212/blob/main/viewReport.dart)

- PS: The code doesn't include button. From the line 162 (SingleChildScrollView) is the target sccafold part. The line 196 is the second widget which is problem

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this can be solved through re-arranging the UI. Can you share your code?

Is it mandatory that all three columns have individual scrolling?

Is it needed that the button needs to be in the third column? If the answer is no, you could Wrap the Container with another Column and finally use a `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. To be more clear, I want to disable the scrolling of all three individual parts. Instead just one SingleChildScroll for the outer container. But somehow the second container get the scroll event which I don't want

Comment: Unfortunately the link to your code gives 404 error.

Comment: Thanks Sk4tOoR!!!! I haven't made the flutter code publicly available. How fool I was. I just made it accessible. Please help, any one with any idea